# Pull-up resistor is running slowly (inverting MOSFET circuit)

Tags: mosfet, motor, pwm, pullup, fet

There's a problem with my fan control circuit.

[image]

It works well, but when I first power up the circuit, the fan runs for about 0.2 seconds. The reason seems to be the time until the pull-up resistor is activated. How can I fix it?

[EDIT]

I'm sorry it took so long.

The purpose of the circuit I'm going to make is this.

A/C & H/T controller

1. Fan speed controlling
2. Relay on/off
3. Temp ADC

I was trying to using a microcontroller but I changed.

I opened some of the products that control the speed of the fan and I found that most products use 555 timer IC.

Of course, my circuit also works normally but I thought using 555 timer IC was simpler and cheaper.

This is my circuit:

[image]

This is cope:

[image]

With this 555 timer circuit, the FET does not heat at all.

Comment: Maybe it's not the pull-up. Maybe 5V rises 0.2 seconds later. Or maybe the chip that outputs PWM pulls the pin low for 0.2 seconds before initializing it high.

Comment: If you have not connected PWM_SIG to anything, then, when the +5V comes up, your fan will be OFF. What is the source of your PWM signal? Do you have a scope which you can use to check the waveform on base of Q2 & Gate of Q4?

Comment: PWM signal is from MCU (Atmega8a)
i programed high signal to 'PWM_SIG' but same.
i don't think the software can solve it

Comment: @KimJiHoon, you have to program PWM_SIG low (not HIGH) to switch ON the motor.

Comment: @sai, my pwm pin is PB1
i programed 'PORT|=(1 << PORTB1)' (i use fast PWM invert mode)
but still not solved
the power to this circuit is always on but will this problem affect circuit life?

Comment: Hi KimJiHoon. Instead of editing _(SOLVED)_ into your question title, please [accept](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that helped you most. This will automatically flag your question as solved. If none of the answers solved your problem, you can add your own answer and accept that one.

Comment: @Velvel oh i will edit, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with user @sai, who suggests the problem is caused by the +5V rail rising way too slowly, leaving Q2 switched off, and allowing the MOSFET Q4 to be switched on by R10 to +BATT.

To fix that, we need to make Q2's default state, in the absence of +5V or a PWM signal, correspond to the motor being off.

Also, your current scheme inverts the "meaning" of the PWM signal, so that low duty cycle corresponds to the motor being powered most of the time, and vice versa.

Both of these problems can be fixed by adding another inverter stage between Q2 and Q4:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUFX2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At this high PWM frequency of 20kHz, the delay between the input's falling edge and Q4's gate following suit, will be a significant chunk of the entire cycle. This is caused by the BJTs taking forever to recover from deep saturation:

[image]

This can be mitigated by preventing the transistors from saturating so deeply, which we can achieve with a little emitter degeneration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flgFjb.png)</sup>

You might notice base and gate resistances R9 and 22Ω are gone, we don't need them any more. I made some changes to R2 and R3, and added R4 and R5, which have the effect of reducing gain and saturation, allowing the transistors to recover much more quickly:

[image]

If I got those values right (and I believe I did), the circuit will work well from 5V or 3.3V PWM input, and any +BATT potential from +20V to +30V. I do not think this design is suitable for battery voltages outside that range.

Also, since R6 and R7 divide the battery voltage by two, you can get rid of D1. The IRLR7843's maximum \$V_{GS}\$ (±20V) will not be exceeded.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply
i have some questions
1. R2 -> pull up Q3
2. R3 -> limit current Q2
is this correct?

3. isn't it better to use a zener diode(D1)?
   (i used zener diode for less heat and R6,R7 resistors (0.5W) need more space)

If i need to add more transistors
is it more effective to configure totem pole circuits?
i have a plan to make a PCB

Comment: @KimJiHoon You don't need a zener diode if you're sure \$V_{GS}\$ can't exceed the maximum. If you use a MOSFET with 12V max \$V_{GS}\$, then it would be necessary. The IRLR7843 doesn't need one in this application, since it's physically impossible for gate potential to exceed +14V.

Comment: @KimJiHoon In my first circuit, you could say that R2 is a "pull-up" resistor, holding Q3 off, unless Q2 "pulls" it low via R3 . In the second one, though, we have left the crude realm of "thumping" the transistor hard, to be emphatically, digitally, "on" or "off". It's less brutal, more "analogue", in that R2, R3 and R4 establish much less emphatic extremes. The same can be said of R5, R6 and R7. They are all chosen to establish precise and deliberate currents and potentials everywhere, not really "bang it on" and "bang it "off" "pull-ups" and "pull-downs".

Comment: i understand what this circuit do
and i think the gate of Q4 will need a resistor like 10R~100R, as it is obvious that the temperature of Q4 will increase
i'm going to try this circuit and other circuits. i have to order the parts, so it will take some time

Comment: @KimJiHoon Q4 in my designs does not need any additional gate resistance. Gate current is already capped by R6 and R7.

Answer (score 1):

R6 has to charge up the base capacitance before Q2 turns on.  In the mean time, R10 is charging up the gate capacitance 10x faster and turning on Q4.  Then after Q2 turns on it has to discharge Q4 gate capacitance.

Make R6 smaller and R10 bigger to get the timing closer and prevent turn on.

Comment: I can't imagine this spurious "on" condition lasting more than 200µs, let alone 200ms.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your problem initially. After reading your question again, it seems you have a power sequencing problem. I am guessing that your BATT comes up first and the +5V comes up only 0.2s later. Thus, base of Q2 is low upon powerup and this makes gate of Q4 high and hence motor is ON for a duration of 0.2s.

**Edit: Solution 1**
The supply of the pull-up resistor can be made BATT instead of +5V and the resistor value can be made 100k.

**Edit: Solution 2**
This is a more complex solution and not so elegant. If you want to retain the +5V as pull-up for some reason, you can add a circuit that detects that +5V is available and keep gate of Q4 pulled down until +5V is ready. Here is one such idea.

[image]

I added pull-down M3 to define the gate low. The pulldown will be active until +5V is ready. Thereby, the motor will be OFF even though the +5V supply comes up late.

Comment: thank you for your answer
i wanted to solve this issue without changing my circuit too much
but if i have to, I'd rather choose a non-inverted circuit

Comment: @KimJiHoon, good idea, the non-inverting solution sounds much simpler.

Comment: @KimJiHoon, I haven't tried it out but, if the pullup is connected to BATT instead of +5V, it might work. You can then change the pullup resistor value to 100k so that it is equivalent to what you have now. I will add this to my answer if it works for you. If it works, it will be the least change to your circuit

Comment: "pullup is connected to BATT instead of +5V"
will the BJT not be damaged?

Comment: @KimJiHoon, no, it won't because we have the 100k resistor between which will limit the current to a reasonable value. Why do you think it will get damaged?

Comment: i forgot to mention it. BATT is 23~30V(it doesn't really matter i think)
and if i connected to BATT, is a diode required for the PWM pin from MCU?
(PWM pin --> diode --->2N2222A base)
or if I add a 5.1V Zener diode(ground--> zener diode -->PWM pin), won't it affect the PWM signal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145810/discussion-between-sai-and-kimjihoon).